# Is there a way to publish a website from github or cloud9IDE directly to a web-host?

Tags: github, web-hosting, cloud9-ide

Is there a way deploy a website directly from github or cloud9 ide? using ftp or other way, right now it doesn't matter what hosting, just so it'll be fully functional and accessible online.

(I know github has a web-hosting of a kind but it seems very limited)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What webframework/language are you using? If you use RoR or Sinatra or any other rake-based framework you can use [heroku.com](http://www.heroku.com). If your using asp.net you can use [appharbor.com](http://www.appharbor.com), finally if your using php you can use [phpfog.com](http://www.phpfog.com).

What these hostingproviders have in common is that you deploy the website by pushing your code with git, while you won't be deploying directly from github you can just add one of the above mentioned hosts to your remote-list (in addition to github) and then push to that remote when you wish to deploy.

Another solution would be to add a post-receive-hook to github which then triggers whenever you push to github, in that post-recieve-hook you could tell the webhost to pull from the repo. This does however require you to have git installed on the webserver aswell as some kind of webinterface for the post-recieve-hook to post to.